# Remove partial duplicate row using column value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to clean data where there is a lot of partial duplicate only storing the first row of data when the key in Col A has duplicate.

```
    A       B    C     D
0   foo     bar  lor   ips
1   foo     bar      
2   test    do    kin  ret
3   test    do     
4   er      ed    ln    pr
```

expected output after cleaning

```
    A       B    C     D
0   foo     bar  lor   ips
1   test    do    kin  ret
2   er      ed    ln    pr
```

I have been looking at methods such as drop_duplicates or even group_by but they don't really help in my case : the duplicate are partial since some rows contain empty data and only have similar value in col A and B.
group by partial work but doesn't return the transformed data , they just filter through.

I'm very new to panda and pointer are appreciated. I could probably doing it outside panda but i'm thinking there might be a better way to do it.

edit: sorry just noticed a mistake i made in the provided example. ( test had became " tes "

Comment: did you try ```df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A'], keep='first')```

Comment: @Aritesh It won't work for `tes` and `test`

Comment: it was my mistake. it was indeed test on both raw sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case how would you say partial duplicate? Please provide complicate example. In the above example instead of Col A duplication you could try Col B.

Expected output could be obtained from this following snippet,

```
print (df.drop_duplicates(subset=['B']))
```

**Note: Suggested solution only works for the above sample, it won't work when it has different col A and same Col B value.**